# Bluebook citation to Virgina Statute

Tags: statutes, virginia, legal-citation

The staute that I am citing:

[image: statute]

What I think the citation is:

```
Va. Code Ann. § 18.2-30 (2021).
```

However, I am unsure about what the year would be and if there is a supplemental or even what is the currentness?

Comment: Bluebook Rule 12.3.1(e) for Supplemental and Bluebook Rule 12.4(e) or 12.5 for currentness (the parenthetical at the end telling through ... legislation/ Sess.)